Azure Policy Not Reflecting Namespace Exclusions in Azure Kubernetes Cluster
I have an Azure Security Benchmark assigned at the Management Group level.
The Azure Security Benchmark has a policy (/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/423dd1ba-798e-40e4-9c4d-b6902674b423) that requires Kubernetes clusters to disable automounting API credentials.
I have an Azure Kubernetes Cluster in the subscription that is part of the above said Management Group on which Azure Security Benchmark is applied, and I'm trying to override the Namespace exclusions to include additional namespaces beyond the default Namespace exclusions list.
My exclusion namespace list is as follows:
[
  "kube-system",
  "gatekeeper-system",
  "azure-arc",
  "azuredefender",
  "mdc",
  "azure-extensions-usage-system",
  "ingress",
  "cert-manager",
  "external-dns",
  "external-secrets"
]

This is compared to the default exclusion namespace list:
[
  "kube-system",
  "gatekeeper-system",
  "azure-arc",
  "azuredefender",
  "mdc",
  "azure-extensions-usage-system"
]

To achieve this, I applied the following policy assignment:
resource "azurerm_resource_policy_assignment" "automounting_allowed_namespaces" {
  name                 = "automounting-allowed-namespaces"
  display_name         = "List of the allowed namespaces for automounting API credentials"
  policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/423dd1ba-798e-40e4-9c4d-b6902674b423"
  resource_id          = var.k8s_cluster_id

  parameters = jsonencode({
    excludedNamespaces = {
      value = [
        "kube-system",
        "gatekeeper-system",
        "azure-arc",
        "azuredefender",
        "mdc",
        "azure-extensions-usage-system",
        "ingress",
        "cert-manager",
        "external-dns",
        "external-secrets"
      ]
    }
  })
}


Despite this, I still see these namespaces under the Affected Components in the Azure policy. I have waited for 4 hours after applying this, would it take 24 hours to reflect?

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can resolve it?
Update: 14 May 2024
As you see below, Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials policy is a part of the Azure Security Benchmark as well as I have applied the same directly on the AKS resource

Defender in AKS shows 26 PODS are affected without excluding the namespaces that I wanted to exclude using the policy applied at the resource level.

Defender for Cloud shows the same as above (26 PODS are affected)

Azure Security Benchmark compliance shows the same as above (26 PODS are affected)

The Custom policy assignment that I assigned at the AKS resource level excluded all the namespaces as I wanted

I have assigned the custom policy assignment at the AKS resource level, it would not override the Azure Security Benchmark and exclude the namespace as per the custom policy? If not, the only way to achieve this is to update the Azure Security Benchmark Policy to exclude the namespaces? I don't have a permission to update the Azure Security Benchmark policies

If no effect type is selected while assigning the policy in Terraform code to disable automounting API credentials in Kubernetes clusters, by default, it will take 'Audit'. However, 'Audit' will not disable it; it will only audit the resources

Would it override the configuration for the given resource as initiative associated at the management group level?

Yes, does initiative assignment have an effect type of 'deny'?

It's set to be audit

To disable it, set it to 'Deny' and check the result.

I have updated the question, please refer the section - Update: 14 May 2024

As per the blog post - https://www.stefanroth.net/2020/01/17/azure-policy-how-precedence-works/
If you apply a policy it gets inherited to the child elements like management group, subscription and resource group. If there is a more restrictive policy it will always win independently of the level it has been applied. Meaning, it does not matter if the policy is applied on management group or resource group level. If policies are not conflicting, they will be complementary, which means they will sum up in its effect.
